# How to use javascript (or something) to make a grid with dragable points that will modify a curve in realtime?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, charts

I want to make a box on the page that contains a graph with a curve on it, then user can drag a few points around modifying the curve. Preferably javascript or something I can easy share variables with DOM and ASP.NET. I want to get out a certain number of the points. Creating new points and deleting them would be great too. This way I could have a movable curve as well as an ability to select the number of coords they can save to database.

Oh yeah the curve is log(n) base, whatever I guess 10 default?

Comment: log(n) is base 10, ln(x) the natural log.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this in javascript then I would suggest you not worry about the asp part, but just focus on the functionality you want, first.

You will want to look at the HTML5 element, `<canvas>`, and for IE you will want to get excanvas.js, http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/.

For a tutorial on canvas you can start here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial

This will enable you to have a drawable surface where you can capture mouse click and mouse move events, as well as other javascript events, so you can have the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to let the user draw a curve, I think you will want to look into using splines. This will let you compute a curve by defining points in 2D space. See, for example:

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~baker/java/hoefer/Spline.htm

I am not sure about the logarithmic base, though.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jQuery plugin](http://jcurvy.com/) that allows you to position elements along the curve.  On the home page, I have implemented what you are talking about in order to help generate curves.

It uses a combination of jQuery, jQuery UI and the [jCurvy](http://jcurvy.com/) plugin to achieve this.  I'd recommend looking at the source on the home page, but here is the code that handles most of it:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
                start: function () {

                },
                drag: function () {

                    $('.dot').remove();
                    var curId = $(this).attr('id');
                    var pos = $(this).position();
                    var param;
                    switch (curId) {
                        case 'x1y1':
                            x1 = pos.left;
                            y1 = pos.top;
                            break;

                        case 'x2y2':
                            x2 = pos.left;
                            y2 = pos.top;
                            break;

                        case 'start':
                            x0 = pos.left;
                            y0 = pos.top;
                            break;

                        case 'finish':
                            x3 = pos.left;
                            y3 = pos.top;
                            break;
                    }
                    param = {
                        "x0": x0,
                        "y0": y0,
                        "x1": x1,
                        "y1": y1,
                        "x2": x2,
                        "y2": y2,
                        "x3": x3,
                        "y3": y3
                    };

                    $('.curve').curve(param);
                    $('#sampleCode').text('$(".mySelector").curve(' + JSON.stringify(param) + ')');
                    $('#demoLink').attr('href', 'demo.html?p=' + JSON.stringify(param));
                },
                stop: function () {
                }
            });
```